# MongoDB Recursive follow to documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am creating a Timeline App.
I am using MERN Stack for it.
I have my personal Timeline. And this Timeline will have certain Events in it.

Eg. Personal Timeline:

```
Friends Birthday:02 April,
College Event: 04 April,
Exam: 06 April.
```

But, to make it more easy. I am going to add a feature of "follow timeline".
For eg. I am studying in XYZ college. So, the events taking place in my college should also be displayed in my Timeline. For this, I will follow my college Timeline.
This is the probable Schema for it.
[image]

But the problem I am facing now is:

If I follow my division Timeline. My division follows Third year Timeline. Third year follows college Timeline. And College follows University Timeline.

SO, if University adds some new event in their timeline. Then I want that all Timelines following University should also have this new event in their Timeline.(In this case College,third year, B-division and personal timeline should have this new event.) How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.